# Redirect uppercase URL's to lowercase version specific to a subfolder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've tried using the mod_spelling but ran into issues, I was hoping to achieve this by just using htaccess. Similar to this ( taken from [this post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18670/how-to-redirect-convert-any-url-to-lowercase)) (however this would lowercase all the URLs I assume)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond expr "tolower(%{REQUEST_URI}) =~ /(.*)/"
RewriteRule [A-Z] %1 [R=301,L]
```

I'll need this to happen in a specific subfolder, anything in this subfolder should 301 to lower case version

For example

```
www.example.com/subfolder/This-Would/Need2-to_Be-Lower
www.example.com/subfolder/another-Example/Be-Lower/Please_33
```

After the "subfolder" it shouldn't matter how deep it goes and/or if there are numbers

This is for a joomla site if that helps at all

Any insight is appreciated here

Comment: Joomla has additional features to handle redirects.  When you have Joomla questions, you will be more likely to gain Joomla-specific insights from [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  Anubhava is a member there too, so he can answer these types of questions there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this rule for a subfolder only:

```sh
RewriteCond expr "tolower(%{REQUEST_URI}) =~ /(.*)/"
RewriteRule ^subfolder/[^A-Z]*[A-Z] %1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Here the pattern `^subfolder/[^A-Z]*[A-Z]` will match a URI that starts with `/subfolder/` and has at least one uppercase letter somewhere.